# I most strongly object!

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I had a comment deleted and than had an answer converted to a comment on this question, [Why does DSCOVR's camera EPIC see at least 13 sunrises and sunsets per day?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/17452/why-does-dscovrs-camera-epic-see-at-least-13-sunrises-and-sunsets-per-day) NASA occasionally posts [woo](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Woo) instead of science, particularly so in its youtube videos. The question was asked because that woo posted by NASA served to confuse rather than educate. The user who asked this question at our site was not the only one who was confused by the confusing statement in that video. (Google it.)

Calling that woo out as woo is the answer to the question. I most strongly object to the conversion of my answer to a comment.

Comment: How can I request a name change,  for this site only? I no longer want my true name associated with this site.

Comment: You can change your name on any site separately from any other site. No moderator intervention necessary.

Comment: Follow this link: http://space.stackexchange.com/users/edit/2752

Comment: You should know that this means I will no longer contribute. I have 30+ years experience in this very field. Do you want to lose that experience?

Comment: David, can we continue this in a designated chat room?

Comment: @kimholder -- That would be a good idea.

Comment: @DavidHammen It would truly be a loss, but we cannot allow experience to be a factor that allows individuals to bypass the system. I hope you will agree to join us in chat about this issue.

Comment: I made this one for it: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43087/comment-conversion

Comment: [woo is real!](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/28127/12102) thanks for pointing this out @DavidHammen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree, calling out woo is a meta-objection, and thus is an appropriate concern to raise on Space Exploration Meta, not in answer to the question itself (comments may be a precursor to a meta discussion). Feel free to ask a meta question about handling questions related to NASA woo.